# Configuration steps for an Azure Windows Server VM with Chef

Tags: azure, chef-infra

I am attempting to learn chef and configure a windows server image that will form the baseline for my production server.

I want to understand what steps I need to take to achieve this.

I have tried to use `knife azure` but had some problems configuring the instance. What I would like to do now is to create a VM, manually install chef onto it and then connect it up to the hosted Chef server.

I understand that I need to do something with WinRM but how do I configure the VM so that it has access to the hosted chef server and I can manipulate it with `knife`?

Do I need to somehow configure WinRM to allow connections from Chef?

Answer (score 0):

The steps to do this are as follows...

1. Confirm that a firewall port is open for WinRM on the target machine for port 5986 (TCP).
2. Confirm that a firewall port is open (if required) on your upstream firewall, or an endpoint has been added for this port if say using a Windows Azure virtual machine.
3. Configure WinRM on the target machine using Powershell...

   winrm quickconfig -q

   winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="300"}'

   winrm set winrm/config '@{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}'

   winrm set winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'

   winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'

   netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM 5985" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=5985 action=allow

   netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM 5986" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=5986 action=allow

   net stop winrm

   sc config winrm start=auto

   net start winrm
4. You can then use the `knife boostrap winrm` command from your Chef workstation (where you installed the Chef Development kit [DK]) to bootstrap the machine and register it with your Chef server e.g.

`knife bootstrap windows winrm [IP Address] -x [Login] -P '[Password]'`

More information at: https://github.com/chef/knife-windows